# Is the combat ability charge for a single battle or for the entire game?

Tags: the-captain

For instance, JEFF has a combat ability to +10 energy as shown below:
[image: jeff ability]

JEFF can repeat it 10 times. So, is it 10 times for each battle or 10 times throughout the game?

Is it possible to "recharge" people ability if it's for the entire game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just finished the game and the case presented in the question, the use is for the entire game. If you use it in one battle, it will go to 9. On the next battle, it will be 9 and if it reaches 0, it's over. You can't reuse or refill.

Some other cards have a description showing times per battle. In times per battle they can be reused in other battles as many times it allows in that battle, but they generally drain something, like energy.